# Is this matrix symmetric, skew-symmetric, or orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Are the following matrices symmetric, skew-symmetric, or orthogonal? Find the spectrum of each, thereby illustrating Theorems 1 and 5. Show your work in detail.

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 8\\
-8 & 2
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

So is it orthogonal? My book says a matrix is orthogonal if:

> orthogonal if transposition gives the inverse of A,

When I do $A*A^t$ I get:

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
68 & 0\\
0 & 68
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Is this an identity matrix or no?

Comment: C'mon, you can do this! 

Comment: Anyway, your $AA^T$ ain't right!

Comment: What do you mean by *an* identity matrix? *The* identity matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and nothing more!

Comment: edited my question, I had the values of the matrix wrong

Comment: It's not orthogonal, but there really should also be an accepted name for matrices like this with $AA^t=\lambda I$.

Comment: So what is this according to the question?